# Comparing the list of elements and string array

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, arraylist

I have the below code

```
public void main() throws InterruptedException {

//expected messages to be displayed in tool tip are as below
   String[] expected_tootltip_Msgs = {"A", "B", "C",
        "D","E","F","G"};

//declaring integer to know the total count
        Integer counter=0;
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        List<WebElement> listImages=driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
        System.out.println("No. of Images: "+listImages.size());
        for(WebElement image:listImages)
        {
            if(image.isDisplayed())
            {
                counter++;
               System.out.println(image.getAttribute("alt"));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No. of total displable images: "+counter);        
  }
```

How can I compare the String `expected_tooltip_msgs` and the output displayed from the list elements?  If both are same my test case would be pass. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is to put the expected Strings into a List (if you expect duplicates) or a Set (if you have no duplicates).

e.g.

```
List<String> expectedTooltips = Lists.newArrayList("A", "B", "C",
        "D","E","F","G"); // this uses the Guava library helper method, you could use List.of if you are using Java 9
...

List<String> actualTooltips = new ArrayList<>();
for(WebElement image:listImages)
{
    if(image.isDisplayed())
    {
       actualTooltips.add(image.getAttribute("alt"));
    }
}

boolean areTooltipsAsExpected = expectedTooltips.equals(actualTooltips);
```

Comment: Would not use list.equals() since it expect both lists members to be in the same order. Likely your made would always return false.

Comment: I would disagree, the user will surely expect the images to be in a particular order, hence you would want to test for that order.